# Не изменяется состояние массива setState React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Не работает setApplication, в консоль всегда выводит applications.length = 0

```js
// useApplications.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useApplications = () => {
    const [applications, setApplications] = useState([]);

    const addApplication = (newApplication) => {
        console.log('applications.length (before state update):', applications.length);

        setApplications(prevApplications => ({
                ...prevApplications,
                ...newApplication
            })
        )
        console.log('applications.length (after state update):', applications.length);
    }




    return {
        applications,
        addApplication,
    };
};

export default useApplications;
```

Код с использованием useEffect, добавил зависимости:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useApplications = () => {
const [applications, setApplications] = useState([]);

const addApplication = (newApplication) => {
    console.log('applications.length (before state update):', applications.length);

    setApplications((prevApplications) => [
        ...prevApplications,
        newApplication,
    ]);
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('applications.length (after state update):', applications.length);
}, [applications]); // Добавил applications как зависимость

return {
    applications,
    addApplication,
};
};

export default useApplications;
```

Код App.js:

```js
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import ApplicationForm from './ApplicationForm';
import ApplicationsList from './ApplicationsList';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">Главная</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/apply">Подать заявку</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/applications">Заявки</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/apply" element={<ApplicationForm />} />
                    <Route path="/applications" element={<ApplicationsList />} />
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

function Home() {
    return <h2>Title</h2>;
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './styles.css';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />

    </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

ApplicationForm.js:

```js
// ApplicationForm.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import useApplications from './useApplications';

const ApplicationForm = () => {
    const [applicantName, setApplicantName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [patronymic, setPatronymic] = useState('');
    const [faculty, setFaculty] = useState('');
    const [group, setGroup] = useState('');
    const [applicationType, setApplicationType] = useState('scholarship');
    const { addApplication } = useApplications();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newApplication = {
            applicantName,
            lastName,
            patronymic,
            faculty,
            group,
            applicationType,
        };

        addApplication(newApplication);

        setApplicantName('');
        setLastName('');
        setPatronymic('');
        setFaculty('');
        setGroup('');
        setApplicationType('scholarship');

        // После сохранения заявки переходим на страницу "Заявок"
        navigate('/applications');
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {*Форма заявки*}

            <button type="submit">Відправити</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default ApplicationForm;
```

ApplicationList.js:

```js
// ApplicationsList.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useApplications from './useApplications';

const ApplicationsList = () => {
    const { applications } = useApplications();
    const [selectedApplication, setSelectedApplication] = useState(null);

    const handleViewDetails = (application) => {
        setSelectedApplication(application);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Список заявок</h2>
            <ul>
                {applications.map((app) => (
                    <li key={app.id}>
                        <strong>{app.applicantName}</strong>: {app.reason}{' '}
                        <button onClick={() => handleViewDetails(app)}>Переглянути деталі</button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>

            {selectedApplication && (
                <div>
                    <h3>Деталі заявки</h3>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Ім'я:</strong> {selectedApplication.applicantName}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Прізвище:</strong> {selectedApplication.lastName}
                    </p>
                    {/* Другие поля которые нужно отобразить */}
                    <p>
                        <strong>Дата та час подання:</strong> {selectedApplication.timestamp.toString()}
                    </p>
                    <button onClick={() => setSelectedApplication(null)}>Закрити</button>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ApplicationsList;
```

Comment: Чтобы увидеть изменения, используйте `useEffect`. Так вы не увидите измеений ибо изменение выполняется асинхронно.

Comment: @Oliver Patterson я уже пробовал использовать useEffect, но это не помогло, возможно я его где-то не там использовал?

Comment: _я уже пробовал использовать useEffect, но это не помогло,_ - очевидно ты неверное его использовал и пока ты не покажешь код как

Comment: @Grundy добавил код с использованием useEffect

Comment: ты не добавил зависимости - поэтому коллбэк вызывается каждый раз, а не только когда длина изменилась

Comment: @Grundy добавил зависимости, но это не помогло, изменил код выше

Comment: @Ярик, добавил пример в ответе: с зависимостью все работает как и ожидается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом блоке кода не хватает указания зависимости в `useEffect`

Если их добавить - `console.log` вызывается после обновления зависимости:

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

const useApplications = () => {
  const [applications, setApplications] = useState([]);

  const addApplication = (newApplication) => {
    console.log('applications.length (before state update):', applications.length);

    setApplications((prevApplications) => [
      ...prevApplications,
      newApplication,
    ]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('applications.length (after state update):', applications.length);
  }, [applications]); // Добавил applications как зависимость

  return {
    applications,
    addApplication,
  };
};

const App = () => {
    const {
      applications,
      addApplication
    } = useApplications();

    return ( < div > {
          applications.map((a, i) => < div key = {
              i
            } > {
              i + 1
            } - {
              a
            } < /div>)} <
            input type = "button"
            value = "add"
            onClick = {
              () => addApplication(Math.random())
            }
            /> <
            /div>)
          }

          ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render( < App / > )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Извините, это не совсем то что мне подходит, я попробовал это внедрить в свой код и ничего не получилось, я добавил код всех компонентов, можете посмотреть и сказать что нужно исправить?

Comment: @Ярик, у тебя в каждом из компонентов свой собственный список `applications` - поэтому тебе кажется что что-то не работает

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь всё работает